# Transfer function of a frequency shifting system

Tags: fourier-transform, transfer-function, laplace-transform

There is a system which shifts frequencies of input by $-F_c$ such that:
[image]

> $$Y(S) = X(S).H(S)$$

But $X(S)$ has value zero from $0$ to $F_c$.

I am confused on how the product of $X(S)$ and $H(S)$ becomes a positive value in $Y(S)$ in that frequency range, for any $H(S)$?

How transfer function of the system $H(S)$ will look like in the frequency domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system you're looking for cannot be described by a transfer function because it is a *time-varying* system. Only linear time-invariant (LTI) system can be fully characterized by a transfer function. However, there is no LTI system that can shift frequencies. The output of a (stable) LTI system can only have frequency components that are already present in the input signal.

Frequency shifts are usually achieved by modulation, i.e., by multiplying the input signal with a sinusoid or with a complex exponential. Such a system is linear but not time-invariant.

Answer (score 3):

While the answers that point out that a system needs to be LTI to have a transfer function is correct, there isn't a lack of trying.

Tymerski, Richard. "Application of the time-varying transfer function for exact small-signal analysis." IEEE Transactions on Power Electronics 9.2 (1994): 196-205.

Kamen, Edward W., Pramod P. Khargonekar, and K. R. Poolla. "A transfer-function approach to linear time-varying discrete-time systems." SIAM journal on control and optimization 23.4 (1985): 550-565.

these are only a few Google hits. There is more.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency shifting system is not **LTI**, and therefore neither its impulse response nor its frequency response exists. A continuous-time frequency shifting system can be described by the following I/O relationship:

$$ y(t) = \mathcal{T} \{x(t) \} = e^{j\omega_0 t } x(t) $$ which is clearly not time-invariant and hence not LTI.

Comment: The impulse response is defined as the system response to an impulse stimulation. That very much exists for this system.  In fact, it exists for all continuous-time linear systems.